# How to send html email templates in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

```
const doc = [
{id: 1, name: 'test1', title: 'hello1', email: 'name@gmail.com'}, 
{id: 2, name: 'test2', title: 'hello2', email: 'name2@gmail.com'}, 
{id: 3, name: 'test1', title: 'hello3', email: 'name@gmail.com'}, 
{id: 4, name: 'test2', title: 'hello4', email: 'name2@gmail.com'}
]

{doc.map(data =>  
  let emailTemplate = fs.readFileSync('./emailTemplates/story-likes.html', { encoding: 'utf-8' });
  emailTemplate = emailTemplate.replace('[name]', data.name);
  emailTemplate = emailTemplate.replace('[title]', data.title);

  const mailOptions = {
                from: 'info@domain.com',
                to: doc.email,
                subject: "Test Subject",
                html: emailTemplate
                }
            
                transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
                if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                }
             })
  })}
```

I want to mail only once the data stored in doc per email but the mail is sent twice probably because I used map the doc. Any Idea how to send in one mail?

example:

In one email

```
name: test1,
title: hello

name: test2,
title: hello3
```

In another email:

```
name: test1,
title: hello2

name: test2,
title: hello4
```

Comment: Mapping function has nothing to do with sending mail twice. 
It is likely that the whole function is running twice

Comment: I have refractor my questions.